# Java classes by default extend object class so if a class extends class other than object does it extends two classes?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I know that every class in java extends Object class by default. Which means that whenever a class extends a class it actually extends two classes? Or whenever a class extends another class it doesnot extends object since the class which it extends already extends object ?

Comment: You can say it extends both classes if you wish to think of it that way, but so long as the two classes have a parent-child relationship then it doesn't really matter.  "Multiple inheritance" (which C++ supports) is where a class inherits from two (or more) classes which are NOT in a parent-child relationship.  It produces some mind-boggling situations (and is a bear to implement efficiently as well). Java uses interfaces to achieve some of the features of multiple inheritance without actually having it.

Comment: The key to this is *'by default'.* If you extend another class, the default doesn't apply, right?

Comment: You have a Doctor class which extend Person. Person extends Object and Doctor extend Person. if a Doctor is a person, and a Person is a object then, a Doctor is also a Object.

Answer (score 2):

No, if it extends another class, it extends a class which extends `Object` (or a different class if the hierarchy is deeper). Each class has a single direct super-class.

Similarly, if class `A` extends `B`, and `B` extends `C`, `A` only has one direct super-class - `B` - even though `C` is an in-direct super-class of `A`.

Comment: Okay got it. I mean I just wanted to make sure:)

Comment: You have a Doctor class which extend Person. Person extends Object and Doctor extend Person. if a Doctor is a person, and a Person is a object then, a Doctor is also a Object.

Comment: @silfrede I'm assuming you are referring to the class that extends another class other than Object, and not `the class that you extend` (which already extends `Object` directly). In that case, yes, the sub-class also extends `Object`, but indirectly.

Comment: You have a Doctor class which extend Person. Person extends Object and Doctor extend Person. if a Doctor is a person, and a Person is a object then, a Doctor is also a Object.